# Finding size of cache in blocks

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-access

Let's say I have a 64 kB Cache provided (i,e 2^18) which is direct mapped and block size is 16 byte = 2^5

Now, in the solution it says 
`m=size of cache in blocks = 4096 = 2^12`. This hasn't been provided in the question. So, how do we assume / derive size of cache in blocks was `2^12`.

If this is a static value, then does that changes if block size is increased to 32 bytes?

Comment: 65 Kilobyte = 2^18. Interesting. 16 byte = 2^5. Also very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the cache in blocks is just the size of the cache in bytes divided by the size of a block in bytes.  However, both the figures you give are wrong: 64 kB is 2^16 bytes, and 16 bytes is 2^4 bytes.  Dividing we get 2^12.